# Problema al leer caracteres con Scanf en C

Tags: c, scanf

Tengo un problema con el siguiente programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    printf("Ingrese el primer caracter:\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    printf("Se leyó el caracter: %c\n", a);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo caracter:\n");
    scanf("%c", &b);
    printf("Se leyó el caracter: %c\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Sólo me deja leer el primer caracter y después termina el programa. La salida es la siguiente:

```
Ingrese el primer caracter: a 
Se leyó el caracter: a 
Ingrese el segundo caracter:
Se leyó el caracter:
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C maneja buffers, tanto de entrada como de salida. Lo que hace la función `scanf` es ir al buffer de entrada `stdin` y tratar de retirar el formato que le indicaste (en este caso, un char). En el primer caso, como el buffer está vacío, el programa se va a quedar esperando que ingreses algo por teclado, en tu caso ingresaste una `a` y presionaste la tecla `enter` la cual fue interpretada como un `\n`. En este momento el buffer de entrada tendrá lo siguiente `a\n`. La función `scanf` retirará el caracter `a`  y retornará al programa. El segundo `scanf` hará lo mismo que el primero, pero esta vez va a encontrar algo en el buffer de entrada, el `\n`. C interpreta el `\n` como un caracter y lo imprime en pantalla (no se ve porque la consola lo interpreta como un salto de línea).

**Solución:**
Para hacer `scanf` con caracteres individuales, añadí un espacio en blanco antes del `%c` para saltear cualquier espacio en blanco y los saltos de línea.

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Para los formatos `%d` y `%s` esto se hace automáticamente y no es necesario el espacio en blanco.

*Cuidado:* por ahí encontras una solución haciendo `fflush(stdin)` antes del `scanf` para limpiar el buffer de entrada. Esto no es correcto debido a que `fflush` sólo está definido para streams de salida, el comportamiento con `stdin` no está definido (aunque en algunos entornos ande, es un error utilizarlo).

También te recomiendo no dejar funciones que no reciben parámetros implícitamente en blanco. Utilizá la palabra `void` asi: `int main (void)`

**Tu código quedaría asi:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a, b;
    printf("Ingrese el primer caracter:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    printf("Se leyó el caracter: %c\n", a);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo caracter:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &b);
    printf("Se leyó el caracter: %c\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta. Funcionó!

Answer (score 0):

después del scanf puedes poner:

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

y eso te permite leer el siguiente carácter en el siguiente scanf()

Answer (score -3):

Lo solucione de una manera diferente pero me funcionó, la demostración que hiciste explica mejor todo. Yo lo resolví poniendo dos scanf seguidos así:

```
int main()
{
    char a, b;
    printf("Ingrese el primer caracter:\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    printf("Se leyó el caracter: %c\n", a);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo caracter:\n");
    scanf("%c", &b);
    scanf("%c", &b);
    printf("Se leyó el caracter: %c\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```