# ¿Por que no puedo leer caracteres en C?

Tags: c

Apenas acabo de retomar mis practica de c y me encuentro con este problema, no se por que sea ni por que pase, pero necesito resolverlo ya!
Cada que intento leer un carácter con: `scanf ("%c",&a);` Compilo normal sin ningún error pero al correr el programa la entrada no funciona corre hasta el final sin mas. No se que hacer... 
El código completo del programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//

int main (){

    float Gc=0,Gf=0,Gk=0;
    char opc;

    printf("\n\t:- Digite la cantidad de grados celcius: ");
    scanf ("%f",&Gc);

    printf ("\n:- Desea convertir a:");
    printf ("\n:- a) Grados Kelvin.");
    printf ("\n:- b) Grado Farenheit.");
    printf ("\n\t:-> "); scanf ("%s",&opc);

    Gf = (Gc * (9/5)) + 32;
    Gk = Gc + 273.15;

    if (opc == 'a' || opc == 'A'){
        printf ("\n\t:- %.2f Grado Celcius, son %.2f Farenheit.",Gc,Gf);
    }
    else if (opc == 'b' || opc == 'B'){
        printf ("\n\t:- %.2f Grado Celcius, son %.2f Kelvin.",Gc,Gk);   
    }


    //system ("break");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto, pues desde una imagen no solo es difícil leerlo sino además copiarlo para reproducirlo

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pega el código, de otra forma será difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Y de paso comprueba que lo que preguntas está de verdad en tu código, porque no es el caso.

Comment: Vale ya esta, me pueden ayudar? quiero continuar y no puedo :T

Comment: De paso, el hombre se llamaba 'Fa***h***renheit'...

Comment: `*(9/5)` no hará lo que quieres. Es lo mismo que `*1` o simplemente omitirlo enteramente, porque es una division de numeros enteros. Tienes que hacer un float por lo menos de uno: `9.0f/5` functionará.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema ocurre por el salto de linea anterior, al indicar que deseas leer un carácter con el especificador **%c** debes dejar un espacio en blanco para indicarle al especificador de conversión que no tome en cuenta el salto de linea anterior.

[aquí se comenta mejor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92331/problema-al-leer-caracteres-con-scanf-en-c).

***Solución***

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//

int main (){

    float Gc=0,Gf=0,Gk=0;
    char opc = 0;

    printf("\n\t:- Digite la cantidad de grados celcius: ");
    scanf ("%f",&Gc);

    printf ("\n:- Desea convertir a:");
    printf ("\n:- a) Grados Kelvin.");
    printf ("\n:- b) Grado Farenheit.");
    printf ("\n\t:-> "); 
    scanf (" %c", &opc); // fijate en el espacio en blanco antes del '%c'

    Gf = (Gc * (9/5)) + 32;
    Gk = Gc + 273.15;

    if (opc == 'a' || opc == 'A'){
        printf ("\n\t:- %.2f Grado Celcius, son %.2f Farenheit.",Gc,Gf);
    }
    else if (opc == 'b' || opc == 'B'){
        printf ("\n\t:- %.2f Grado Celcius, son %.2f Kelvin.",Gc,Gk);   
    }


    //system ("break");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: PD. No estaría de más que corrigieran *Celsius*  (-.-') Y tampoco hay grados Kelvin. La unidad es Kelvin, a secas

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo @Alfabravo, se deben corregir, lo que quise fue decirle como solucionar el problema, hay validaciones que se deben hacer de lógica y de conceptos que quedaran por parte de __KaneKiSa586__.

Comment: Por cierto, el espacio, que comentas, en este caso no es para descartar espacios sino **el salto de linea** que ha introducido la llamada anterior a `scanf`... claro que también se descartan espacios (si los hubiese)... pero no es el problema que nos ocupa. Que no hay que olvidar que en C la lectura es bloqueante hasta que se introduce un salto de línea. Cualquier otra lectura de `scanf` descarta dicho salto de línea... es con `%c` cuando aparecen estos problemas

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario @eferion, tienes toda la razón, edité la repuesta y deje un enlace donde lo explica mejor.

Comment: Mucha gracias por su ayuda.