# Intento hacer un menú que se tiene que volver a ejecutar

Tags: c

Buenas soy nuevo tanto en esta página como en en programación. No sé si sea un error simple o no pero el problema que tengo es que al ejecutar una vez el menú por alguna razón inserto el valor que quiero se ejecuta correctamente pero luego se ejecuta solo insertando un número 10 no se que significa.
Se que se puede escribir sin usar números de la tabla `ascii` pero no me anda igual

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
char n;
do{
        printf("|J|ugar;)\n|V|er apuestas:3\n|S|alir:(\n");
        scanf("%c",&n);
        printf("%d\n",n);
        switch(n){
         case(106):case(74):;
         break;

        case(118):case(86):;break;

        case(83):case(115):printf(" Chau\n");break;
        default:printf("Fuera de rango\n"); 
        }
}
while(n!=83&&n!=115);
}
```

Comment: Es una característica del buffer de C al tratar de leer un dato tipo char. [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92332/80870) solucionará tu duda. Por otro lado, si la función principal es `int()`, debe retornar algo al final, así sea `return 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya han comentado, tu problema está en el buffer (al poner una letra, por ejemplo, 'a' en realidad se está introduciendo 'a' '\n', y tiene que eliminarse):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char n;
    do {
        printf("|J|ugar ;)\n");
        printf("|V|er apuestas :3\n");
        printf("|S|alir :(\n");

        scanf("%c%*c",&n); // el '%*c' indica al compilador de obtener otro caracter, e ignorarlo
        printf("%c\n",n);

        switch(n) {
            case('J'):
                printf("Jugar\n\n");
                break;
            case('V'):
                printf("Apuestas\n\n");
                break;
            case('S'):
                printf("Chau\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Fuera de rango\n\n"); 
        }
    } while(n != 'S');

    return 0;
}
```

Extras:

1. No uses valores ASCII (aunque funcione, no siempre puede hacerlo y resulta muy molesto de trabajar así)
2. Como también comentaron, el main siempre ha de terminar en `return 0;`
3. Respeta espaciado (si entras en un if, pulsa una vez 'tab', así resulta mucho más cómodo leer el código)
4. Personalmente, encuentro mejor hacer dos `printf` en vez de hacerlo todo en uno, pero esto a gusto del programador